# Is there any way that I can include my own function file under any file?

Tags: c

I wrote my frequently used functions in a file. Is there a way that I can include it in any folder through the include command without using absolute paths? My files are placed on the linux server and I can only operate in my personal directory.

Comment: Do you always want to recompile your functions file for every project? Or do you prefer to create one object file once and link to it during compilation? Anyway .. consider the 2nd option. Also consider using `make` and its makefiles.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to do it.